# Modify a commands to an original values

Tags: shell, arithmetic

I am  working with terminal in Linux and have some problems. I need to make a script contains these commands in pico and then to execute it. I've already done this  and my output is 254 9 23 -45 and now I need to modify those lines where base 16 and base 8 numbers appear to print the original values respectively in base 16 base 8.

```
    printf "%d\n" 0xfe
    printf "%d\n" 011
    printf "%d\n" 23
    printf "%d\n" -45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the "conversion specifier" for this, e.g.:

```
$ printf '%#o' 8
010
$ printf '%#x' 16
0x10
```

Comment: Do I need to write it exactly like this?                                                               $ printf '%#o' 8
010
$ printf '%#x' 16
0x10